Projecting (distance, azimuth) point in geographic coordinates with PyQGIS
I have a point in WGS84 (EPSG:4326) for which I would like to calculate a projection based on an azimuth and a distance in meters.
This is basically what does QgsPoint::project but in Cartesian, so looking for the corresponding method for geographic coordinates.
Accuracy is not super important.
